# Need assistance regarding displaying custom separator on UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I trying to conditionally draw a separator on `UITableViewCell` so first of all I set `[self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];` and then in my `UITableViewCell` subclass I did this

**.h file**

```
@property BOOL separator;
```

**.m file**

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    if(self.separator)
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor colorWithRed:188.0/255.0 green:186.0/255.0 blue:193.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor]);
    else
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 0.5);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 55.0, self.bounds.size.height);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);
}
```

and inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method I am doing this

```
        if(indexPath.section == 0) {
                if(indexPath.row == 0) {
                    cell1 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell1"];
                    cell1.lbl1.text = name;
                    cell1.lbl1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:17.0];
                    cell1.separator = YES;
                }
        }

// other cells with different identifiers...

        if(indexPath.section == 5) {
            cell1 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell1"];
            cell1.lbl1.text = @"March 25";
            cell1.lbl1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Regular" size:1.0];
            cell1.separator = NO;
            return cell1;
        }
```

In section 5 I don't want to display separator so I did `cell1.separator = NO;` but why I am still getting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that your `drawRect:` method is not called on the cell object after dequeueing the cell. You can try to add a setter for `separator` property and call `setNeedsDisplay` within it, like this:

```
- (void)setSeparator:(BOOL)separator
{
    _separator = separator;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

This will cause the invocation of your `drawRect:` method after assigning a new value to `separator` property.

Answer (score 1):

It may be redrawn since table cells are reusable. Try to erase it if separator property is false.